# a synchronization issue between requests in express/node.js

Tags: node.js, express, concurrency, synchronization

I've come up with a fancy issue of synchronization in node.js, which I've not able to find an elegant solution:

I setup a express/node.js web app for retrieving statistics data from a one row database table.

- If the table is empty, populate it by a long calculation task
- If the record in table is older than 15 minutes from now, update it by a long calculation task
- Otherwise, respond with a web page showing the record in DB.

The problem is, 
when multiple users issue requests simultaneously, in case the record is old, the long calculation task would be **executed once per request**, instead of just once.

Is there any elegant way that only one request triggers the calculation task, and all others wait for the updated DB record?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is called *locks*.

Put an additional column in your table say *lock* which will be of timestamp type. Once a process starts working with that record put a `now+timeout` time into it (by the rule of thumb I choose timeout to be 2x the average time of processing). When the process stops processing update that column with *NULL* value.

At the begining of processing check that column. If the `value > now` condition is satisfied then return some status code to client (don't force client to wait, it's a bad user experience, he doesn't know what's going on unless processing time is really short) like `409 Conflict`. Otherwise start processing (also ideally processing takes place in a separate thread/process so that user won't have to wait: respond with an appropriate status code like `202 Accepted`).

This `now+timeout` value is needed in case your processing process crashes (so we avoid deadlocks). Also remember that you have to "check and set" this *lock* column in transaction because of race conditions (might be quite difficult if you are working with MongoDB-like databases).

Comment: Is there any way that can get rid of the DB table r/w access lock?